# How to keep updating the data with SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I am working on a Reporting Database for the decision-makers in my company so that I got the accesses from 3 different SQL database and 1 SAP server.
I built 4 SSIS to map the raw data from those databases and loaded them into the reporting one to build Power BI mostly.

However, I don't know which way is a good practice to keep the reporting database updating. For example, when a new record is created in the SQL server of the Sales Department, I want it will come to the reporting as well.

I only saw SSIS could do the ETL one time, and the data I got is just until the moment I finished the first execution. If I do one more time, it will be duplicated all records loaded before with some new records.

Please give me a hint from your perspective, thank so much.

Comment: IF you dont have a create and update date in your tables, add them.  Then you can query only on those records that changed since the last time you ran it.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, but you'll need to redesign your solution.  SSIS can handled this, you just have to build your packages to do it.  Depending on amount of data and other factors you could have your SSIS packages just to a full reload each time they run. Or as the previous comment mentioned if the source has some sort of modified date you can use that to only load new/changed since the last run.  Several ways to go about this.  Once all that is sorted out, deploy the packages and setup an agent job to then run on whatever frequency is needed, once a day, every 2 hours...

Comment: And if you need to repeat the load, simply shedule the execution of your SSIS via agent job accordingly. However, if it comes to "near real time" processing, SSIS isn't the tool of choice I'd say...